# What's this maybe-morse-code "CQ CQ GE EDEN" and "DD" in Le Eden de la Grisaia?

Tags: morse-code

The ending song of an anime television series called *Le Eden de la Grisaia* [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VgJwDeYnPYs) has a light flashing. I suspect it may be Morse Code. By watching the video a little more slowly than usual (frame by frame), it's easy to see that

- dit is 2 frames
- dah is 6 frames
- intra-character gap is 2 frames
- gap between characters is 6 frames
- gap between words is 14 frames

So it probably is Morse Code.

I've managed to translate it into letters. Here's my recording of the transmission. `-` means the light is on.  means the light is off.

At the beginning:

> ```
> --- - --- - --- --- - ---       --- - --- - --- --- - ---       --- --- -   -       -   --- - -   -   --- -
> ```

Which is "CQ CQ GE EDEN". Notice there is only 1 dit's time between "C" and "Q".

And at around 1:25:

> ```
> --- - -       --- - -
> ```

Which is "DD".

I haven't used Morse Code before, so I don't know what these letters mean. What do they mean?

---

**EDIT:**

Thanks to to a comment by Phil Frost. The TV show is Japanese. I looked up the Japanese equivalent of Morse Code, [Wabun Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wabun_code). If it's in Wabun Code, the transmission would be

> リヘ
>   ヘホヘタ

and

> ホホ

Unfortunately, I don't know Japanese. So if anyone who sees this happens to know Japanese, please tell me whether the above makes any sense. Googling yielded no results.

Comment: "GE" instead of "DE", and the "DD" at the end makes me suspect this is either some Japanese convention I don't know, or just the Morse code equivalent of Engrish.

Comment: @Phil, you never cease to amaze me.  I have worked Japan on CW hundreds of times and they stick to the format pretty well.  Never considered that they have their own alphabet.

Comment: @PhilFrost Please see my edit. "DE" would make more sense, but I checked that I didn't mistakenly copy "DE" into "GE".

Answer (score 4):

`CQ` is common in amateur radio (not just morse) as a way to initiate communications. It basically means "anyone who can hear this, please respond if you want to talk".

`GE` could maybe be a typo of `DE` (`-.. .`), which is used in morse and text-based communications to mean "this is" or "from" and usually precedes the callsign of the person sending.

Not sure about `DD`.

Comment: Does "CQ" usually have 1 or 3 dits' blank between "C" and "Q"? I checked again. "GE" is correct.

Comment: I'm not a morse user myself, but I believe it should have the normal gap between letters, but again, it could quite easily be an error.

Comment: DD is probably something like a producer's initials.  I have to laugh when I watch "Last Man Standing" how much ham gear they have.  If you can get away with it, why not show it off.  And since it is not transmitted through ham bands there is no reason for an ID like we use.  It is someone's equivalent to "Sit, Ubu, sit" is my quess.

Comment: DD could be some initials or similar, like @SDsolar suggests, but it just turned up when I ran LCWO's word training with the dictionary set to "CW abbreviations". This makes me a bit suspicious, though I have no idea what it means myself.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps "GE" means "good evening"!

Comment: Eden is in the show title, so maybe it is calling anyone to say Good Evening Eden.  (Although I would use QRZ even in Morse for that)

Answer (score 2):

"CQ CQ *D*E EDEN" would make perfect sense, meaning "This is Eden calling anyone." Though I'm not sure why a submarine would flash that on a signal lamp while submerged. "*G*E EDEN" must be a mistake.

I've no idea what "DD" at the end means. It could be Wabun code. Or it could be someone's initials or similar of significance to the show's creators. Or perhaps an obscure reference to something in the show. Or, another mistake.

Comment: I don't know what DD means either, but it just turned up when I ran LCWO's word training with the dictionary set to "CW abbreviations". Could this be a clue to figuring it out?

Answer (score 1):

A long time ago I lived in Japan for 2 years. I still can speak enough Japanese to hold a conversation. This seems to be just gibberish. It actually sound more like something real in English than Japanese, at least to me. Using online translators also yielded no results.